# which folders to ignore in a codeigniter app when using version control

Tags: php, codeigniter, version-control

Which folders should I ignore when using version control on a project developed on the CodeIgniter framework?

I am already ignoring the application/cache folder, but are there any else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can ignore any application generated logs and any development specific configuration files.  Here's a commonly used .gitignore file for CodeIgniter:

```
*/config/development
*/logs/log-*.php
*/logs/!index.html
*/cache/*
*/cache/!index.html
```

https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/CodeIgniter.gitignore

Answer (score 3):

Beyond the default github codeigniter template provided by birderic, (at https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/CodeIgniter.gitignore for good measure) I also like to simply exclude any php file in the /config director with

```
*/config/*.php
```

Some third party apps, like HybridIgnite, like to put their configuration files in the /config directory and a limited config block might enable on of these files to be tracked... Better safe than sorry...

To make it clear how config files should work, I keep a copy of the default files (with no passwords of course) in a seperate config_template directory.

HTH,
-FT

Comment: This is not good. config.php and route.php files in the config folder may have changes while developing.